# Drag and drop upload displays the wrong prompt in IE and Firefox

Tags: ithit-ajax-file-browser

When using drag and drop upload with Ajax Browser v 2.5.1.1703, Chrome 34 displays the popup "Copy", which is correct. With both IE 11 and Firefox 29 the popup is "Move" which is not correct. Is the incorrect popup being displayed by the Ajax Browser or is the popup an issue with the IE and Firefox. If it's the Ajax Browser, how can it be fixed.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I have forwarded your question to the developer and will post an answer very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Firefox bug or limitation. There is no way to display "Copy" for it, it can display only "Move" for some reason (even thought we set drop dataTransfer.dropEffect correctly). Note that Gmail has the same issue.